# How to add comments in XML using python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-comments

XML i am parsing:

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

In Output XML i want to add a comment above Next_Item:

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <!--Not-Needed-->
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

I tried following:

```
doc = etree.parse('XML1')
for id in doc.xpath('//Item/Price/Next_Item/text()'):
id = etree.Comment('Not-Needed')
root = doc.getroot()
 root.insert(1, comment)
```

Its adding comment at the top of file instead of above 'next_item' element.

As here

root.insert(1, comment) [1 is index]

so is there a way where instead of index number i can pass a variable so i can add comment to number of places . for example whenever it finds 'next_item' it has to add a comment

output i am getting is:

```
<List>
<!--Not-Needed--><!--Not-Needed--><!--Not-Needed--><!--Not-Needed--><!--Not-Needed--><!--Not-Needed--><!--Not-Needed--><!--Not-Needed-->
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

Grateful for your help.

Comment: I don't see that XPath `//Item/Price/Next_Item()` working at all, what are the `()` at the end good for? Have you considered using XSLT to insert the comment nodes?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have changed the path to //Item/Price/Next_Item/text() 
I have never worked in XSLT yet

Comment: Your input sample has four `Next_Item` elements and your text seems to suggest you want to add a comment before each of them, yet your output sample only shows one comment before the first `Next_Item` element. Please clarify.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have edited my question
with XML i am getting and XML I am looking for
root.insert(1, comment) only takes index
but I want to pass a variable which will search  the  Item/Price/Id if its 100 then it will add comment above Next_Item

Comment: @MartinHonnen
As I have never used XSLT yet.

so I wanted to know whether I have to import anything before using it as while using `<xsl : stylesheet
            xmlns: xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version = "1.0" >`
I am getting Unresolved reference 'stylesheet'

Comment: I have edited my answer with a Python sample showing how to use lxml to run the XSLT sample in the answer against the XML sample in your question.

Comment: @Anonymous: The latest edit (rev 7) changed the question substantially. Don't move the goalposts. You have already received two answers. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @mzjn
sorry for inconvinience. I have reverted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below (*Note that no external lib is required*)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
first_price = root.find('.//Item/Price')
first_price.insert(1, ET.Comment('Not-Needed'))
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <!--Not-Needed-->
             <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use case for an XSLT transformation and [lxml supports XSLT 1.0](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item/Price[Amount = 100]/Next_Item[1]">
    <xsl:comment>Not-needed</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So a small Python sample using lxml to run the above XSLT against the shown sample input and write the transformation result to the file `result1.xml` is e.g.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def xslt_usage_example():
    xml = ET.XML("""<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>""")

    transformer = ET.XSLT(ET.XML("""<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item/Price[Amount = 100]/Next_Item[1]">
    <xsl:comment>Not-needed</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>"""))

    result = transformer(xml)

    result.write_output("result1.xml")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xslt_usage_example()
```